# Capture any message on an SMTP service and route to a single email address

Tags: exchange-2007

I have a web server I use as a QA environment for applications before the app deploys to live. A common function is for emails to be sent to a variety of internal or external addresses.

I want to know if the Exchange SMTP is able to be configured to route any email that passes through it to a single mailbox without sending the email to its real recipient. I'd like to also be able to see the intended recipient of the message.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that this is MS Exchange, the only solution I can see for this is to set up a separate Exchange server (on a domain separate from your normal, main domain), with either contacts or mailboxes for all your normal recipients (with forwarding to their usual mailboxes under "normal" circumstances), and then change the forwarding to a new, separate mailbox when in "testing" mode.
You need the separate domain, because MS Exchange is tightly integrated with Active Directory and for what you have in mind you need an AD instance that can be manipulated without affecting normal email traffic.
If you were to use Exchange 2010, you could probably use transport rules to do this in a simpler way, but I am not sure whether this concept actually exists in Exchange 2007.

Comment: Not really what I was hoping to hear but thanks for the info.

Comment: This sort of thing is significantly easier when you use a linux based MTA, e.g. exim. If you don't have any linux skills, this would be jumping in on the deep end. OTOH, if you do have linux skills, exim is the default MTA for many distros and there is lots of help available.

Comment: That's nice. I'm committed to Exchange.